# Firebird functions from Visual Studio DataSet?

Tags: c#, sql-server, firebird

I'm having an issue trying to convert some code from MSSQL to Firebird (don't ask) and wondering what I am doing wrong?

MSSQL: `DAY(timeofevent) as MyDay`

Converting to:

Firebird: `EXTRACT(DAY FROM timeofevent)` - causes errors because VS complains about the 'FROM' here and also it changes the function to read:  `"extract" ( "day" from timeofevent )` and won't run.  If I manually edit the code it will run once, then autocorrect to the above.... How do I properly call a firebird function from a Dataset?

Comment: Could you provide more information on the definition of your DataSet? Do you have the [Firebird DDEX Provider](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/) installed?

Comment: No the FB DDEX chokes on my machine every few days, and I have to reinstall it all the time so i gave up using it.  I'm using ODBC now.  I've also tried using {fn EXTRACT(day from t) as myday} but VS chokes on this as well.